# Python: modbus_tk not responding in slave mode

Tags: python, modbus, modbus-tk

I am trying to make Modbus-RTU slave in python,using modbus_tk library. Below is the basic code which I am trying to make it work.

```
import modbus_tk
import modbus_tk.defines as cst
from modbus_tk import modbus_rtu
import serial

PORT = 'COM1'
modbusServ = 
modbus_rtu.RtuServer(serial.Serial(PORT),baudrate=9600,
                     bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, xonxoff=0)
print("start")
try:
    modbusServ.start()
    print("receiver module started")
    slave_1 = modbusServ.add_slave (1)
    slave_1.add_block ("a",cst.ANALOG_INPUTS,200, 7)
    slave_1.set_values ("a",200,range(7))
    slave_2 = modbusServ.add_slave(2)
    slave_2.add_block ("b",cst.HOLDING_REGISTERS,200,7)
    slave_2.set_values("b",200,range(7))
    slave_5 = modbusServ.add_slave(5)
    slave_5.add_block("c",cst.COILS,0,7)
    slave_5.set_values("c",0,range(1))

    while True:
        slave_1.set_values ("a",200,1)
        slave_1.set_values ("a",201,2)
        slave_1.set_values ("a",202,3)
        slave_1.set_values ("a",203,4)
        slave_1.set_values ("a",204,5)
        slave_1.set_values ("a",205,6)
        slave_1.set_values ("a",206,7)
finally:
    print("ideally do not come here")
```

Once the code is running, I am doing some read queries from another master (i could monitor on com port that the master is making query) but the slave is not giving any response to the query.

Other information

```
 platform: windows 7, 64-bit
 Python version: 3.5.2, 64-bit
 modbus_tk versoin: 0.5.7
```

Is there some thing I am missing? or any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while True` loop is constantly updating data and may take all the CPU.

I would try to have a small delay in this loop. Something like

```
import modbus_tk
import modbus_tk.defines as cst
from modbus_tk import modbus_rtu
import serial
import time  # add this

PORT = 'COM1'
modbusServ = modbus_rtu.RtuServer(serial.Serial(PORT),baudrate=9600,
                 bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, xonxoff=0)
print("start")
try:
    modbusServ.start()
    print("receiver module started")
    slave_1 = modbusServ.add_slave (1)
    slave_1.add_block ("a",cst.ANALOG_INPUTS,200, 7)
    slave_1.set_values ("a",200,range(7))
    slave_2 = modbusServ.add_slave(2)
    slave_2.add_block ("b",cst.HOLDING_REGISTERS,200,7)
    slave_2.set_values("b",200,range(7))
    slave_5 = modbusServ.add_slave(5)
    slave_5.add_block("c",cst.COILS,0,7)
    slave_5.set_values("c",0,range(1))

    while True:
        slave_1.set_values ("a",200,1)
        slave_1.set_values ("a",201,2)
        slave_1.set_values ("a",202,3)
        slave_1.set_values ("a",203,4)
        slave_1.set_values ("a",204,5)
        slave_1.set_values ("a",205,6)
        slave_1.set_values ("a",206,7)
        time.sleep(0.1)   # small delay to let the communication thread doing his job
finally:
     print("ideally do not come here")
```